# Does await Task.Delay(1000) inside new Task() block some thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I have read some docs, and what I learned is that `await Task.Delay(1000)` does not block thread.

But in this code example, it seems that it blocks threads:

```
       var task = new Task(async () => {
                Console.WriteLine(" ====== begin Delay()");
                for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" ===Delay=== " + i);
                    Console.WriteLine("the task thread id: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + "; the task id is: " + Task.CurrentId);
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine("**ddd***:"+i);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(" ====== end Delay()");

            });

            task.Start();
```

it prints:

```
 ====== begin Delay()
 ===Delay=== 1
the task thread id: 3; the task id is: 1
**ddd***:1
 ===Delay=== 2
the task thread id: 4; the task id is:
**ddd***:2
 ===Delay=== 3
the task thread id: 3; the task id is:
**ddd***:3
 ===Delay=== 4
the task thread id: 4; the task id is:
**ddd***:4
 ====== end Delay()
```

as per the print out, it executes the code in a sync way.

I thought it would print some thing like below:

```
 ====== begin Delay()
 ===Delay=== 1
the task thread id: 3; the task id is: 1    
 ===Delay=== 2
the task thread id: 4; the task id is:    
 ===Delay=== 3
the task thread id: 3; the task id is:    
 ===Delay=== 4
the task thread id: 4; the task id is:    
**ddd***:1
**ddd***:2
**ddd***:3
**ddd***:4
 ====== end Delay()
```

So I'm confused, could somebody please explain the behavior? Thanks.

Comment: [FYI](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L5863-L5902)

Comment: You seem to be confusing two different things. Waiting for a process to be completed before continuing doesn't necessarily equal blocking the thread. When you use `await AnyTrueAsyncMethod();`, the thread isn't blocked, however, the next line doesn't get executed until the task is finished.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52863940/does-task-delay-make-sense-on-a-dedicated-thread)

Comment: Which threads do you believe that are blocked? The threads with id 3 and 4? You can test your assumption by starting a second task that will run concurrently with this one and does some similar thing, to see if the threads 3 and 4 will appear in the logs of the other task. If they do, then they are not blocked.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, can you please explain a little more? Thanks.

Comment: [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: @IvanYang Your code is no executed doesn't means current thread is "blocked". See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34706101/4123703

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> inside new Task()

First, I have to say: [never, *ever* use the `Task` constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html). There are exactly zero valid use cases. If you want to run a delegate on a thread pool thread, use `Task.Run`.

> So I'm confused, could somebody please explain the behavior?

Yes, the key is that there's a difference between "imperative" (one step after another) and "synchronous" (blocking the caller).

> as per the print out, it executes the code in a sync way.

No, it is not synchronous at all. It is, however, imperative. [When an `await` decides it needs to wait, it will "pause" its current method and return to the caller. When that `await` is ready to continue, it will resume executing its method.](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

Note that the thread is not blocked. The method is paused. So it is imperative but *not* synchronous.